# Energy of a uniformly charged sphere

Tags: electromagnetism

$$W = {\epsilon_0 \over 2}\int_V E^2 \ dV = {\epsilon_0 \over 2}\int_V (\mathbf E_{in} + \mathbf E_{out})^2\  dV = {\epsilon_0 \over 2} \left(\int_V E_{in}^2\ dV + \int_V E_{out}^2\ dV  + 2\int_V \mathbf E_{in}\cdot \mathbf E_{out}\ dV\right)$$

The first two integral, when evaluated in respective regions, gives the desired result of $\dfrac{3}{5}\dfrac{k q^2}{R}$ implying the cross integral to be zero.

Why is the cross integral zero in this case ?

In general I have a hard time understanding in which region does the cross integral evaluated ? In all over the space or the region formed by the intesection of indiviual electric fields (which is zero in this case) ?

Comment: Could you explain (perhaps with a diagram) what $E_{in}$ and $E_{out}$ are in your example? What are the "respective regions"? How can there be two different values of the field at a single point in space?

Comment: If you are describing $E$ with two different functions - one for $r<=R$ and one for $r>R$, then you just get the first two terms of your second expression (and the first expression with $E_{in} + E_{out}$ makes no sense).

Comment: @Floris But the total field in the space is the field in the sphere and out of the sphere. Then why i can't write $E = E_{in} + E_{out}$ ?

Comment: the field at any given point is just the value at that point. If you want to express it as the sum of the two (where you define both over all space), then where one has a value, the other is zero. In which case the cross product over all space is zero - because one or other is zero at each point in space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually wanted to write:

$$\int_{V_\text{in}} E^2 dV + \int_{V_\text{out}} E^2 dV$$

where $V_\text{in}$ is the inside of the sphere and $V_\text{out}$ is the rest of space outside the sphere.

Comment: I guess you are correct but the total field in the space is the field in the sphere and out of the sphere. Then why i can't write $E = E_{in} + E_{out}$

Comment: $E_{in}=0$ outside of the sphere and $E_{out}=0$ inside of the sphere.